# Android: How to use Parse as an alternative GCM push notification provider?

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

**SEE EDIT#2 at the end of the question (Google updated the way push is implemented so it became easier to handle gcm and parse together)**

I already use GCM inside a application and I would like to add parse as an alternative. This is what I have now (all the permissions are correctly declared):

```
<service 
   android:name="com.mypackagename.GCMIntentService" 
   android:enabled="true" />
<receiver 
   android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
   android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
       <category android:name="com.mypackagename.GCMIntentService" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The 'GCMIntentService' (inherits from 'GCMBaseIntentService') class handles the server registration and receiving of messages - it works fine and all the push messages are received. The server sometimes sends custom data so I handle the messages myself and create the notifications programmatically (the intent used when the notification is clicked has some important extras sent from the server).

I would like to somehow make parse behave in the same way in order to be able to send channel pushes from the parse website and create my own notifications, but everything I tried failed (following the android push tutorial isn't really working for my problem). Is there anyone who tried a similar thing? I'm kind of out of ideas after spending a lot of time tweaking the push guides/tutorials - sometimes I don't receive any notifications; sometimes both parse and my receiver are called and I get double notifications. I also tried to register using parse REST apis and handle everything myself but found out it isn't possible on Android.

So, how could I handle both parse pushes and the traditional gcm pushes (using my server) in such a way that I have access to both notifications and I can build them from scratch (create my own pending notifications with the required extras)?

**EDIT#1:**

The first thing I tried was to use the parse service and have a single broadcast receiver to handle the GCM messages:

AndroidMaifest.xml:

```
<service 
    android:name="com.mypackagename.GCMIntentService" 
    android:enabled="true" />
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService"
    android:enabled="true"/>
<receiver 
    android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" 
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.mypackagename.GCMIntentService" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the parse library requires the following initializations:

```
Parse.initialize(context, appId, apiKey);
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(context, MainActivity.class);
// I'm subscribing to channel push because I send channel pushes from the
// parse console
PushService.subscribe(context, MDConstants.PARSE_PUSH_CHANNEL, MainActivity.class);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

The problem is that I receive the notifications from my other provider but I don't receive anything from parse (all the permissions are declared) and I get the following error from the parse library (when receiving the error the parse registration is not properly done - I can't see my device in the parse console):

```
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): Cannot use GCM for push because the app manifest is missing some required declarations. Please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <permission android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): 
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677):   <intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677):     <category android:name="com.mypackagename" />
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677):   </intent-filter>
E/com.parse.ManifestInfo(11677): </receiver>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <permission android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackagename.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):   <intent-filter>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):     <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):     <category android:name="com.mypackagename" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):   </intent-filter>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): </receiver>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): 
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):   <intent-filter>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):     <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):     <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
E/com.parse.PushService(11677):   </intent-filter>
E/com.parse.PushService(11677): </receiver>
```

**EDIT#2:**

I updated the way gcm push was handled based on the [google push notification developer guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client). While implementing the class that extends 'GcmListenerService', you can now easily check if the 'from' arguments is the same as your google project id used to register for push.

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        // only handle gcm messages that come from the same project id used to register
        if (from.equals("Your google project id)) {
            // handle the gcm push
        }
    }
}
```

Also, parse updated their libraries (I'm using '1.9.4' right now) and you can subclass the 'ParsePushBroadcastReceiver' to handle the notifications as you'd like. See the guide [here](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) for a basic implementation.

Parse initialization in the 'onCreate' method of your 'Application' class:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "your parse app id", "your parse client key");

// subscribing to a channel
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("your channel name", new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push");
        }
    }
});
```

The broadcast receiver implementation:

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // handle the parse push notification
    }
}
```

The manifest declaration for both parse and gcm:

```
...

<!-- GCM listener service -->
<service
    android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

...

<!-- Parse broadcast receiver -->
<receiver android:name=".MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

...
```

I only added the service and the receiver, but you need to make sure you follow the GCM guide and the Parse push guides to have a full implementation (for example, google also added a way to handle the token refresh - a sample containing full code samples can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your code to handle all the incoming GCM messages, regardless of their source (which can be either your server or Parse website), which means you don't want the Parse code in your app do handle them.

You can achieve this by declaring only a single broadcast receiver handling `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE` action in your manifest. That would be your `GCMBroadcastReceiver` class, which would handle all the arriving GCM messages.

The behavior you are currently experiencing can happen when you declare two broadcast receivers that handle the same action.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried but the parse library throws errors if I don't have their declarations inside the manifest (as stated by this tutorial https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications). I updated the question with more details (and of course, having the parse receiver aswell as the GCM one results in double notifications).

Comment: @Spiri In that case I would try to set (in the manifest) the priority of your GCM receiver to a higher value than the priority of the Parse receiver. That way your receiver will always be called first, and after you handle the broadcast, you can prevent if from being sent to the other receiver (by setting the result code to CANCELED if I remember correctly). I haven't tried it myself, so I can't be sure it works, but I think it should.

Comment: When I receive the registration action I have to send the registration id to my server (I registered manually with my google project id) but I'm also receiving the parse registration action (I guess they create google project ids behind the scene) and I managed to differentiate between the two based on which arrives first - this is a hack and I'd like to ask you if you know a better way to recognize between the two registrations

Comment: The problem is that parse registers first then myself and if my registration reaches the parse broadcast receiver it will override the registration id on their server so push notifications won't work from parse). The priority really helped me so I'll mark the answer as valid :)

Comment: @Spiri When receiving a message in the broadcast receiver, you can differentiate between the two based on the "from" field (`intent.getExtras ().get("from")`) which contains the sender ID that was used in the registration. I'm not sure whether that field is also returned when receiving a registration response, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Managed to do this by watching the registration id ('from' doesn't come while registering) but the behavior is still very strange - sometimes I get pushes from both my server and push and sometimes from just one of the providers - do you think that there might be some problems if two providers use gcm for the same application?

Comment: @Spiri I don't understand your last comment. Do you mean messages sent from both your server and parse are handle by the same broadcast receiver? Or that a message from one of the servers is handled by both receivers?

Comment: Nvm the last comment - I still have the problem of differentiating between the registration messages that are received by the broadcast receiver - I have to abort the broadcast if the message comes from my server (in order to avoid the rewriting of the device token by parse) and I can't do that because the intent doesn't contain enough info (only the registration id or errors)

Comment: Have you any idea about how to migrate parse installation data to GCM Server Application (which is create by us PHP)?