# Error setting up push notification using parse in android studio

Tags: android, parse-platform

following the parse.com tutorial for setting up push notification on android (https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications). but getting below error:

```
03-16 14:36:15.280  19899-19952/experties.com.handytask E/com.parse.PushService﹕ Tried to use push, but this app is not configured for push due to: Push is not configured for this app because the app manifest is missing required declarations. Please add the following declarations to your app manifest to support either GCM or PPNS for push (or both). To enable GCM support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="experties.com.handytask.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="experties.com.handytask.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="experties.com.handytask" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
To enable PPNS support, please make sure that these permissions are declared as children of the root <manifest> element:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
Also, please make sure that these services and broadcast receivers are declared as children of the <application> element:
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="experties.com.handytask" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="experties.com.handytask.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:name=".rest.HandyTaskApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ShowTasksActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_tasks" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_chat" >
    </activity>

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBFgfG5NRhQj_nC0aFRi7PAyruYG3lbJdg" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.TaskCreationStep1Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_created" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.TaskCreationStep2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_task_creation_step2" >
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="experties.com.handytask" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/push_icon"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

I refer this posts too, but didn't help.

[Android: How to use Parse as an alternative GCM push notification provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23055519/android-how-to-use-parse-as-an-alternative-gcm-push-notification-provider)

[error setting up push notification using parse.com and android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355187/error-setting-up-push-notification-using-parse-com-and-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your manifest, file, I think the problem lies in the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

You need to change com.parse.tutorials to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"

In your case, this would be

```
<uses-permission android:name="experties.com.handytask.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Basically, your android:name and uses-permission has to match.

Comment: Glad to help, can you mark the answer as correct? That way others who also have this problem can solve it.